# how to print the data from an array of objects in php

Tags: php

i am new to php and object oriented programming , i have any issue i need to print the group value from any array called $inputdata

when i use print_r to print the $inputdata  array it looks like :

```
vision\newsubject\inputdata  Object
(
 [property_state:protected] => Array
                (
                    [newTypeID] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1
                            [value_saved] => 1
                        )

                    [group] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 12
                            [value_saved] => 12
                        )
      )

                )
```

I want to print the group value ,please help me out

Comment: `$inputdata->property_state['group']['value']`

Comment: Do you have an `inputdata` class with methods??? If not, build one with a method that returns that array and call that.

Comment: Note however that `property_state` is `protected`, so you can only directly access it from methods inside that objects class or classes derived from that objects class. You will need a getter otherwise.

Comment: i am getting Cannot access protected propert value error @arkascha

Comment: @vyshnavi http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Protected properties are not accessible from outside the scope of the class and its descendants. Chances are that the class has an accessor function like `getGroup()` that you should be using.

Comment: Which is exactly what I told you in my last comment.

Comment: Me too.  You didn't answer.